# Evaluating Hyperbolic Cotangent (coth) Integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, physics, hyperbolic-functions

I am working on some simulation, and the [paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0168900213013703) that I am basing some of the work off of involves several complex integrals.

In particular, the one I am trying to solve is

$\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\omega}(\coth(\frac{\alpha\omega}{2})\cos(\omega t))d\omega$

(Part of Eq. 4 in the paper I linked)

I found a very similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1462513/help-evaluating-the-integral-int-0-infty-omega-cos-omega-t-coth-alp), but the [method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1436302/integral-involving-the-hyperbolic-tangent/1436615#1436615) given to solve it does not seem to work for me and I'm wondering if the $\frac{1}{\omega}$ drastically changes how I have to go about solving it?

Comment: Where is indep var  $d \omega?$

Comment: Yes, sorry. I added that in now. Hopefully that is more clear.

Comment: The $\coth(a\omega/2)$ is like $2/(a\omega)$ around $\omega=0$, and then you divide by another $\omega$. This means that the integral diverges "very much" at $\omega=0$.

Comment: @mickep yes, the integral diverges. But I don't see why $\frac{1}{\omega}$ makes it impossible to "equate" it to another function as in the linked questions.